# bool doesn't want to change value c++

Tags: c++, boolean

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int x - 0;
 bool even = true;

 while(cin >> x)
 {
   if(x%2 != 0)
   {
     even = false;
   }
 }

 if(even = true)
 {
   cout << "all even";
 }

 else
 {
    cerr << "not all even";
    return 1;
 }
}
```

whenever i run this program, no matter the values I plug in (user ends input by pressing CTRL + D in the console) the value of even stays true, since the ending output is always "all even".

I'm pretty sure the bool doesn't change because it is inside the while statement, but I do not know how to fix it since I need to leave it in there to check if each number I enter is odd.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `even = true` should be `even == true`. Welcome to C++. (`if (even)` would also work). Some compilers give a warning about this if you set the level high enough.

Comment: If you are using GCC to compile, turn on warnings so compiler helps you out -- `g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(even = true)
```

should be

```
if(even == true)
```

"const on the left" people will argue your bug could have been prevented by doing:

```
if(true = even)
```

that way the compiler would have warned you about incorrect assignment.

Comment: actually, it shouldn't be either. it should be `if (even)`. Explicit testing for `true` is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change these lines:

`int x - 0;` to `int x = 0;`

`if(even = true)` to `if(even == true)` or `if(even)`

and probably `cerr << "not all even";` to `cout << "not all even";`

but the line cause your problem is `if(even = true)`, where you *assign* `true` to your `even` variable instead of *compare* it with `true`.